# Concatenated JSON objects in one text file - how to import to R?

Tags: json, r

I have a txt file which is built from many JSON objects. The structure of the file looks something like this:

```
[{"id": 333, "key press:1 ....},{"id":321 ...}, ][{"id": 333, "key press:1 ....},{"id":321 ...}] etc.
```

Trying to read it using either jsonlite (error), rjson or RJSONIO - I get only part of the file - I can import the data until the first closure (the ]). Is there any way to parse it, or to read these objects to R?
I attach a full file (I have many): https://pastebin.com/Ee2cvdEi

Thanks

Comment: I just gave a look at the file and it seems that each line of the file is a JSON (except the first, which appears to be blank). So you have to read a line, call `fromJSON` to the line and move on the next one. You can do this with `lapply(readLines("json_example.txt")[-1],jsonlite::fromJSON)`, which works for the file you linked.

Comment: Thank you. It actually works quite good with your advice.